# Is there a way to connect to on prem oracle database using azure pipeline?

Tags: oracle, azure

I need to connect to on-prem Oracle Database using Azure pipeline. I have created self-hosted agent which runs on the same subnet as the database. I have created a deployment group as well. However, I am not able to find a task that I could add as a stage to the release pipeline that could authenticate the db server using the credentials and run a GET query to pull data. Am I on the right track? Are there other alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please use data factory in Azure to connect Oracle database on-premise. Yes, you should install a self-host Integration runtime for data factory. setup "Linked services" in data factory, so that you can input the credentials/connection string there.
please reference this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction

Comment: I have some requirement that I need to do it through the azure pipeline and not data factory. Hence, looking for a ADO pipeline solution.